# Obtaining a "one-term" lower bound from an exponential sum lower bound of Roth

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, exponential-sums

In the excellent book "A Panorama of Discrepancy Theory", edited by Chen et al, there is a chapter entitled Multicolor Discrepancy of Arithmetic Structures, by Hebbinghaus and Srivastav. From p. 360:

> Roth [1] showed the following estimate for sums of unit roots:$$\sum_{\delta=1}^{2L} \left|\sum_{j=0}^{L-1} \exp(2 \pi i \delta j \alpha)\right|^2 \geq  \left(\frac{2}{\pi}L\right)^2,$$ for arbitrary $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$

This estimate is straightforward to see by expanding the sum and converting to a ratio of sinc functions.

Later on, on p. 380, the authors state Lemma 105 which states

> Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $L$ be a natural number. Then there exists an integer $\delta \in \{1,2,\ldots,2L\}$ such that:$$ \left|\sum_{j=0}^{L-1} \exp(2 \pi i \delta j \alpha)\right|^2 \geq  \left(\frac{2}{\pi}L\right)^2,$$

and claim that it is an immediate consequence of Roth's estimate.

How does it follow? The right hand side is the same and the left hand side is just one term.

1. Roth, K.F., Remark concerning integer sequences, Acta Arithmetica,Vol. 9, pp. 257-260 ('1964)

Comment: The second is not a consequence of the first, but look at Roth' paper (first lines on page 259): There exists a $q$ in $1 \leq q \leq Q$ and an integer $h$ such that $|q  \alpha - h| \leq Q^{-1}$, and this implies the bound on the exponential sum. This is what you have here, just that $Q$ is $2L$ etc.

Comment: Thank you! I must have had a serious brain freeze... Feel free to write this as an answer